# Best way of dealing with state on embedded devices

Tags: c, embedded

The classical issue on single-core embedded devices:

```c
void blink() {
  set_main_diode(HIGH);
  delay(200);
  set_main_diode(LOW);
  delay(200);
}
```

This will hog-up CPU, so other, real-time components of the device (like USB etc.) are not ticked, until this is performed. Of course, we have for this purpose an RTOS, but I don't want to use RTOS.
What is the best way of dealing with states? I liked this [State Machine Design in C](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1275479/State-Machine-Design-in-C), although I would like to see any other designs of state machines or ways how to deal with states.

Comment: Maybe toggle the led from a timer interrupt?

Comment: use not blocking way of delaying. For example Arduino millis.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, but I bit wrongly written what I'm asking. My question is about other designs of state machines or or ways how to deal with them. Example upper is just as classic example, where the function will hog up all other things "on the background".

Comment: The standard way to implement things like LED blinking, is to have some manner of general-purpose timer running in the background, such as ARM "Systick". Make it so that it triggers a cyclic interrupt on even intervals (once per 1ms, 10ms etc). Then simply either increase a counter or toggle the LED upon that interrupt. If you are actually asking about state machines, then maybe not the best example since toggling a LED can also be 100% outsourced to hardware by using PWM or output compare features of the timer hardware.

Comment: Similar question on EE: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355496/finite-state-machine-handling-timers-gracefully

Comment: It is too "opinion based" for SO, the best answer is the one that works for your application.  Miro Samek _literally_ wrote the book on the subject: https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Practical_UML_Statecharts_in_C_C++.html?id=XrWPsLzH9WoC, and his company provide a framework for it: https://www.state-machine.com/

Comment: Since the community at SE apparently doesn't want this question (or anything related to program design), you could ask it at Codidact instead. General program design questions can be asked at https://software.codidact.com/ and embedded systems design questions at https://electrical.codidact.com/

Answer (score 1):

If the embedded device is only flashing the LED, it's not a problem to waste the CPU resources. Even if you have an interrupt-based code, you will have to waste CPU cycle at some point:

```
interrupt function Timer100ms ()
{
  // state machine implementation
  // to toggle the LEDs
}

void main ()
{
  InitializeLED();
  InitializeTimers();

  while (true)
  {
     // do nothing, waiting for the LED to flash
  }
}
```

Comment: `while(1);` "wastes" the same number of resources as delay()

Comment: But if using interrupts, the program could do other meaningful things in the meantime.

Comment: Yes, absolutely!

Answer (score 1):

The classic way to implement bare-metal real-time systems is to use code similar to the state machine you linked, based on function-pointers. But it's not actually a state machine, as much as a list of tasks to execute. A manner of "poor man's RTOS", which actually contains everything that a RTOS does save for context switching and separate process stacks. It might look like this:

```
typedef err_t task_t (void);

static task_t* const TASK [TASK_N] = 
{
  display,
  uart,
  leds,
  ...
};

void main (void)
{
  /* misc init code here */

  err_t result;
  size_t task_count = 0;
 
  for(;;)
  {
    kick_wdog();

    result = TASK[task_count]();

    if(result != OK)
    {
      error_handler(result, task_count);
    }

    task_count++;
    if(task_count == TASK_N)
    {
      task_count=0;
    }
  }
}
```

Here, every function in the `TASK` list is assumed to be non-blocking. Foe example if it polls for various flags, it should preferably do with with `if(REG & FLAG)` rather than `while((REG & FLAG)==0)`. And each module/driver keeps track of its internal state. This means maximum utilization of CPU.

The watch dog should be configured so that it kills the program if one individual task takes too long to finish. Additionally, you may start a hardware timer before each task is executed. Then you can check how long it took to finish.

In real-time systems you usually have a cyclic time that all tasks are supposed to finish in, for example 10ms. That means that you would first wait out the 10ms cycle before doing setting the task counter back to zero. During this time, you could optionally put the MCU in sleep mode to save current.

This is also how you often design high integrity systems where the watch dog is using a "window mode", meaning that it has to be fed within certain time intervals not to reset.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the simplest method would be using timers. You set the LED to high and also start a timer. In the interrupt handling routine, you can then turn the LED off and disable the timer.
If you want constant blinking, you can simply have a timer for that, and in the ISR, you can just toggle the LED.
I would not go for an RTOS for some LED blinking, it seems to me that that would be quite an overhead.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example the solution is trivial:

```
void blink() 
{
  static output_t led_state = HIGH ;
  static clock_t last_toggle = clock() ;
  clock_t now = clock() ;
  
  if( last_toggle - now >= 200 )
  {
    last_toggle = now ;
    led_state = led_state == LOW ? HIGH : LOW ;
  }

  set_main_diode( led_state ) ;
}
```

In general however your question is too broad.  The solution should be appropriate to your task.  You could implement a sophisticated state-machine architecture, but if all your states are time triggered rather than event triggered it may be over-kill.

There is a general principle that can be taken from the above - simply that state is stored in static data.

Comment: Note that if you take @Lundin's answer and make this `blink()` implementation one of his `TASK` functions, you have your self the beginnings of a general purpose "big-loop" framework.  That is each `TASK` in his framework should be a state-machine of some form.  That is easier to manage than "one big state-machine" as the functional partitioning is much clearer.

Comment: Indeed, and it is much also easier to overview than a "state machine of state machines", because if each task keeps track of it's own state machine, it is privately encapsulated. I recall once making a fairly large and complex program which revolved around a state machine of state machines. Implemented as an array of arrays of function pointers, which means quite evil C syntax. Alas, nobody in my team understood a thing of what my code did. So I ended up rewriting the whole thing with private encapsulation per individual state machine.